# How can I provide a clickable link in a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I would like to write a text in my title but have the word be a clickable link like a 'Link' or 'a'. Title is only waiting for a string.

```
<MaterialSwitch
 title={A CLICKABLE STRING}
/>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You should use something like Bootstrap's tooltip (see here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/ )

Comment: Then whatever `MaterialSwitch` is will need to support that feature. If it deals in strings of text then it deals in strings of text and you would need to change it so it supports a component instead.

Comment: Did you write the `<MaterialSwitch />` component by yourself, or does it come from an NPM package? If an NPM package, please (always) **link to it**, so we can avoid doing wild guesses...

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of **HtmlTooltip** instead of Tooltip .
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/#main-content

```js
const HtmlTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }) => (
  <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />
))(({ theme }) => ({
  [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f9',
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
    maxWidth: 220,
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(12),
    border: '1px solid #dadde9',
  },
}));


<HtmlTooltip
        title={
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography color="inherit">Tooltip with HTML</Typography>
            <em>{"And here's"}</em> <b>{'some'}</b> <u>{'amazing content'}</u>.{' '}
            {"It's very engaging. Right?"}
          </React.Fragment>
        }
      >
        <Button>HTML</Button>
      </HtmlTooltip>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only solution i see is making your custom Tooltip, or just implement one from a library. Then you can add an onClick that directs you to a new Page.

Maybe you wanna take a look at MaterialUI
https://mui.com/components/tooltips/

```
<Tooltip onClick={() => redirect(...)} title="Add">
  <Button>Controlled</Button>
</Tooltip>
```

here is what it could look like in MaterialUI

Answer (score 1):

If the clickable links are present in some dynamic string and you want to render that string as a real html then you can make use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` e.g

```
<Tooltip interactive
  title={<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: functionWhichReturnsHtmlString() }} />}
>
  <IconButton><ChatBubbleOutlineIcon fontSize="small" /></IconButton>
</Tooltip>
```

Second option is usage of [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

```
<Tooltip interactive
  title={<div>{ReactHtmlParser(functionWhichReturnsHtmlString())}</div>}
>
  <IconButton><ChatBubbleOutlineIcon fontSize="small" /></IconButton>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were wondering where to put the onClick event, try passing the onClick callback using the [PopperProps](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tooltip/) property, something like this:

```js
    <Tooltip
       PopperProps={{
         onClick: () => {
           console.log('click')
         }
       }}
    >
      child text node
    </Tooltip>
```